# How to handle click in a nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, interface, listener

Can someone explain the logic on how to handle this matter:

I have a fragment that after a WebSocket call inflates 2 Recyclerviews.

Child Recyclerview is nested to Parent Recyclerview and the parent adapter calls the child adapter. 
I want to put an Interface for a click listener which handles the click in the Child Items in the Fragment.

Where should I put the interface and which class should implement it?

Comment: Go with expandable list view, that will be better for the nested list.

Comment: I am inflating buttons and gridviews in the secondary Recyclerview. I cant go with ListView

Comment: I am talking about the expandable-list view, for your reference https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying to do has been done multiple times.

There are various approaches you can try, but in general, responsibilities would  look something like this:

#### `YourContext` (Fragment/Activity)

- Inflates a layout with a `RecyclerView`.
- Instantiates `YourAdapter`
- Subscribes, Requests, Waits, for your data and passes it onto `YourAdapter`.
- Maintains an interface for click handling, like:

```
interface YourThingClickHandler {
   fun onThingWasClicked(thing: Thing) // and any other thing you may need.
}
```

- Can be `YourContext: YourThingClickHandler` or if you want, you can keep an anonymous/local instance of that. I usually do the former and then implement the `fun onThingWasClicked(...)` in the fragment/activity, it depends what you need to do when the item was clicked.

#### `YourAdapter`

- Expects a list of `Things` *and* one `YourThingClickHandler` instance. So in your Fragment/Activity you'd do, something like (pseudo code):

```
// This is called once your ViewModel/Presenter/Repository/etc. makes the data available.
fun onThingsLoaded(things: List<Thing>) {
    adapter.setClickHandler(this) // this can be passed when you construct your adapter too via constructor like adapter = YourAdapter(this)
    adapter.submitList(things) // if the adapter extends a `ListAdapter` this is all you need.
}
```

Now that you've passed an outer click handler, you need to deal with the inner list. Now you have a few choices: 
1. pass the same click handler all the way in and let the `innerAdapter` directly talk to this.
2. Have the `outerAdapter` act as an intermediate between the clicks happening in the innerAdapter and bubble them up via this click handler you just supplied.

Which one you chose, will depend largely on what you want to do with it, and how you want to handle it. There's no right or wrong in my opinion.

Regardless of what you do, you still need to get *from the view holder* to this click handler...

So in `YourAdapter` you should have another Interface:

```
    interface InternalClickDelegate {
        fun onItemTappedAt(position: Int)
    }
```

This internal handler, will be used to talk from the viewHolder, back to your Adapter, and to bubble the tap up to the external click handler.

Now you can have a single instance of this, defined like so in your adapter class (remember this is Pseudo-Code):

```
    private val internalClickHandler: InternalClickDelegate? = object : InternalClickDelegate {

        override fun onItemTappedAt(position: Int) {
            externalClickHandler?.run {
                onThingWasClicked(getItem(position))
            }
        }
    }
```

So *if* the external click handler (the `YourThingClickHandler` you supplied) is not null, then fetch the item from the adapter's data source, and pass it along.

#### How do you wire this internal handler with each view holder?

When you do `onCreateViewHolder`, have a ViewHolder that takes... you guessed, a `InternalClickDelegate` instance and so...

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        // decide which viewHolder you're inflating... and...

       return YourViewHolder(whateverViewYouInflate, internalClickHandler)
```

Now your ViewHolder(s) have a reference to this internal click handler...

so when you do `onBindViewHolder(...)` you probably call a common ViewHolder method of your choice, for example if your View holder can be of different types, you probably have an Abstract viewHolder with a `fun bind(thing: Thing)` method or similar that each concrete viewHolder subType will have to implement... in there, you'd do something like this:

```
override fun bind(thing: Thing) {
   if (clickHandler != null) {
       someViewYourViewHolderInflated.setOnClickListener(this) // this assumes your ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener from the framework
   }
}
```

Because your ViewHolder implements `View.OnClickListener`, you must implement the onClick method in it:

```
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        clickHandler?.onItemTappedAt(adapterPosition)
    }
```

And this is how your ViewHolder, will receive the tap/click event from Android in the `onClick` method, if you supplied a click Handler (you did in the adapter onCreateViewHolder when you passed the internalClickHandler), it will simply bubble the tap, passing the position. `adapterPosition` is the Kotlin equivalent of calling `getAdapterPosition()` in a RecyclerView adapter.

### TOO LONG, DIDN'T READ GRAPH

- **Fragment**: ExternalClickListener -> passes an instance of it to the Adapter.
- **Adapter**: Receives the ExternalClickListener, passes an InternalClickListener to each ViewHolder.
- **ViewHolder**: Receives the internal Click Listener, sets itself as Clickable (either the entire `itemView` or just any widgets you want to make clickable, if you want the whole cell to be clickable, simply use `itemView` which is the "whole" view of the ViewHolder.

When the viewHolder's view is tapped, android calls the click listener's `onClick` method. In there, and because you are in a ViewHolder, you can do getAdapterPosition() and pass this to the `internal` click handler you received.

The Adapter then can transform that position back into data, and because you supplied an External `clickListener`, it can pass the actual item back to the external click listener.

#### Wait, but how about a NESTED RecyclerView.

There's nothing special about that, you simply need to provide the same mechanism, and keep passing things around. What you do or how many of these interfaces you have, depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve; like I said at the beginning, each solution is different and other factors must be taken into account when making architectural decisions.

In general, keep this thing in mind: **Separation of Concerns**: keep things small and *to the point*. For E.g.: it may seem crazy to have this double interface, but it's very clear what each does. The internal one, is simply concerned about a "tap" in a "view", and to provide the position in a list where said tap occurred.

This is "all" the adapter needs to fetch the data and make an informed guess at what item was truly tapped.

The fragment doesn't know (or care) about "positions", that's an Adapter's implementation detail; the fact that `positions` exist, is oblivious to the Fragment; but the Fragment is happy, because it receives the `Thing` in the callback, which is what most likely needs to know (if you needed to know the position for whatever reason, tailor and modify the `externalCallback` to have the signature of your choice.

Now replicate the "passing hands" from your OuterAdapter to your InnerAdapter, and you have done what you wanted to do.

Good luck!

Comment: This actually helped a lot. Thank you for your time spending on this. I managed to fix the series of interfaces and listeners. I was trying to get fixed answers(sub Recyclerview) on a chat app to be able to be clicked and get sent to a server.

Comment: You could just write a full example. It would be more readable...! Good explanation though..!

Comment: @james04 I could, but SO is not a coding site, it's a Q/A site. It's BYOC™ situation (Bring Your Own Code). I believe with the information provided and the multitude of information online, it should be fairly trivial to have this implemented, and a lot easier to ask a more specific question when it doesn't.

Comment: @james04 Here you have it https://github.com/Gryzor/TheSimplestRV/tree/nested_recyclerviews (keep in mind I spent a couple of hours on top of that simple project, adding the horizontal "nested" RV and modifying the Model to _conveniently_ make it easier. The problem I notice out of the box is `DefaultItemAnimator` sucks, and the inner RV doesn't keep its position. I may have made a mistake, but seems like maybe ListAdapter/DiffUtil.Callback aren't doing a 100% good job there. Or maybe I made another mistake, but I'm sure interested parties can fix it and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should put interface in child adapter and implement that in parent and then pass another one interface (long peocess)

2) Use local broadcast manager

Answer (score 0):

you will add ClickListener in parent adapter and also add it in constructor of adapter

```
public interface HandleClickListener
 {
    void onItemClicked(int position, SurveysListModel surveysListModel);
   }
```

Make an instance of your clicklistener and then on holderclick listner get the position of item and its value from your model list

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                handleClickListener.onItemClicked(position, yourModelList.get(position));
});
```

and get in to your activity like this making an instance of you adapter

```
adapter = new InstrumentsSearchAdapter(yourModelsList, activity.this, new SearchAdapter.HandleClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClicked(int position, Model listModel) {
                        instumentChild = listModel.getInstrument_title();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Listing.class);
                        intent.putExtra("selectedQuestions", listModel.getQuestions());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
                    }
                });
```

And if you want to go to parent recyclerview class implement onActivityResutlt method and get data back from child through intent and get that intent in onActivityResutlt method